# VueNative: Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)

Tags: vue.js, vue-native

This is my first `vue-native` app. And I am getting this error:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) 
or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `ExpoRootComponent`.
```

[image]

package.json

```js
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~40.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.3",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.0-beta.0",
    "vue-native-core": "0.2.0",
    "vue-native-helper": "0.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.0.0",
    "vue-native-scripts": "0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I have already tried to create the project several times and googled for the solutions but every time I am getting this error.